# Meteor play YouTube videos on popup

Tags: meteor, youtube, popupwindow

is there any option to play youtube videos  popup window  in Meteor.

im using `adrianliaw:youtube-iframe-api` to play videos

included these two in

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and i downloaded `jquery.youtubepopup.min.js` file and included as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.youtubepopup.min.js"></script>
```

finally in my html

```
<a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eYSpIz2FjU">title</a>
```

on Templte onRendered() in initializing like this `$("a.youtube").YouTubePopup(options);`

referred link   http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/#Examples  but dint worked for me

Thanks 
Manju

Comment: Please post *your* code instead of the link with several snippets.

Comment: @hubert-og: added code spinets please let me know if you need more info